# SPFX Terminal error - Javascript heap out of memory

Tags: spfx, solution

When I hit the command gulp serve i am getting this error in terminal, and the gulp serve is getting terminated due to the issue.

[image]

Earlier this solution working fine since last 4 months. There is around 99GB space on my d rive, where this solution is located.

I tried couple of things in last few days but unable to get the resolution.

What i have understand so far is, it is somewhat related to the node js memory management.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It is not an issue with drive space, it is a RAM related issue. Have you seen this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory

Comment: Yes, But this does not have solution for spfx case.

Comment: I just now got the solution, gulp serve --max-old-space-size=8192

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with a leak in the ts-loader. The issue comes from NodeJS 8 where they introduced really low memory cap 1.4GB per NodeJS process. The only option to get around this limitation is to start gulp server using the following command.

```
gulp serve --max-old-space-size=8192
```

This will set the appropriate Node flag to use a max of 8Gb or whatever value you pass in.

Answer (score 1):

For some reson when `gulp serve --max-old-space-size=8192` added as npm script flag doesnt get applied